# VBA - Excel: Search value in File1 and import it to File2

Tags: vba, excel

I have two Excel Files. The first one contains values that are related to persons and that are available on a monthly frequency. 
[image]

I want to extract these values per month and import them to a second file. The second file has a similar structure as the first one, the order of the person names and the distance between the rows are different.

Here is what I have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wkb1 As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim wks1 As Worksheet

    zeileErsterName = 8
    spalteName = 2

    ChDir "Dir"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= File2.xlsm"
    Set wkb = Workbooks("File2.xlsm")
    Set wkb1 = Workbooks("File1.xlsm") 
    Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("Jan-Dez")
    Set wks1 = wkb1.Worksheets("Overview")

    Monat = ListBox1.Value
    MonatBudget = wks1.Cells.Find(What:=Monat).Column
    Monat = Left(Monat, 3)
    MonatBeleg = wks.Cells.Find(What:=Monat).Column
    While Not IsEmpty(wks.Cells(zeileErsterName, spalteName))
        Name = wks.Cells(zeileErsterName, spalteName).Value
        zeileName = wks1.Cells.Find(What:=Name, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Row
        zeileStaffingtage = zeileName + 1            
        wks1.Cells(zeileStaffingtage, MonatBudget).Value = wks.Cells(zeileErsterName, MonatBeleg).Value
        Debug.Print wks1.Cells(zeileStaffingtage, MonatBudget).Value
        zeileErsterName = zeileErsterName + 2
        wks1.Name = "Overview"
    Wend

    Workbooks("File2.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

The first problem is that the name of the Worksheet changes in the loop and takes the name of the person.

The second problem is that the values from File2 are not always transferred to the proper position in File1.

Thank you for some help.

[image: File1 & File2]

File1 is the target file, I want to import the values from File 2 - column "Jan" - into the row "Belegplan" at the respective name.

Kind regards

Comment: Your first problem is caused by the fact that you are using a variable named "Name" which is a reserved key word in VBA, you should amend the name of that variable to something else, like SearchName for example...

Comment: And for your 2nd problem have you debugged line-by-line to see what is happening? `The values are not always transferred to the proper position` is hard for us to detect without more information (like sample data or screenshot).

Comment: The first problem is now solved, thank you. I added a screenshot with the data.

Comment: Unfortunately, the screenshot does not help as it does not describe your problem and even the text you use to describe it is misleading as there is no `Belegplan` in the screenshot. Review [mcve] then update your question to something we can work with. (Just the process of creating the mcve for yourself may answer your question!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I hope it is comprehensible now, I added the complete screenshot.. hope you can work with it

Comment: @Csap5032 - That helps a lot. We are almost there. No tell us where the values populate instead of where they are supposed to. At initial review the code appears to be doing what it needs to ...

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Name1 does not take the new values, the rest is fine..

Comment: in the line that sets `zeileName` change `After:=ActiveCell` to `After:=wsk1.Range("A1")`.